# How to map variables in a data frame to terms in a model matrix in R?

Tags: r

Given a formula, is there any way to make R tell which variables that "contribute" to each separate term in the formula? Example:

```
f<-y~x+x*z+I(x^2)+log(x) 
attr(terms(f),"term.labels")
# [1] "x"      "z"      "I(x^2)" "log(x)" "x:z"
```

The variable `x` contributes to terms 1, 3, 4, and 5. Thus, I would like to have a function which outputs `c(1,3,4,5)` when given the input `c(f,"x")`.

Comment: maybe `grep("(?!<[[:alnum:]._])x(?![[:alnum:]._])", attr(terms(f),"term.labels"), perl=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you don't use functions that return `NA` when passed `1`:

```
f<-y~x+x*z+I(x^2)+log(x)

whichFormula <- function(f, var) {
vars <- all.vars(f)
n <- length(vars)
DF <- data.frame(matrix(1, ncol=n, nrow=1))
names(DF) <- vars
DF[1, var] <- NA
mm <- model.frame(f, data=DF, na.action=NULL)
unname(
  which(
    is.na(
      unlist(
        .External2(stats:::C_modelmatrix, 
                   terms(f), 
                   mm)[1,])[-1])))
}
whichFormula(f, "x")
#[1] 1 3 4 5
```